# Firebase: how to delete range of items inside node based on timestamp keys?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**My Firebase database data looks like this:**

[image]

- The numbers are timestamps in seconds (so the data is basically a
  time series).
- I want to delete all the data OLDER then 5 seconds.
- I am using the new `Version 9 Modular JavaScript SDK's`

**So for example if we take that current time is `1637149389` I want to delete all the data according to the picture below:**
[image]

**I tried using this code but the result is that my whole path to the data is deleted (including data not older then 5 seconds):**

```
var timestamp = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000) - 5; //get Timestamp in Mili, convert to Seconds, and then set it 5 seconds to the past
var UID = 'uid1';

const ref = ref(
    database,
    'device_realtime/' + UID
);

var refQuery = query(
    ref,
    ...[fb.orderByKey(), fb.endAt(timestamp.toString())]
);

remove(refQuery);
```

- I am little confused because when I call `get(refQuery)` on the same
  query my results are correct.
- I only see data older then 5 seconds!

**Console:**

[image]

### How would I delete only certain range of items based on their timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a node, you need to know the complete path to that node. Firebase doesn't support update/remove queries, where you pass the root reference and a condition to the database.

So you'll need to call `remove()` on each individual child node that you want to remove.

Something like:

```
get(refQuery, (results) => {
  results.forEach((snapshot) => {
    remove(snapshot.ref);
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)